# My BF program worked yesterday but doesn't today

Tags: brainfuck

I know that may seem silly, but yesterday, I found out about Brainfuck, and had fun with it.
I made some programs and had a lot of fun.

Though, today, when I try the same program, it simply prints nothing.
I first did this-

```
++++++++++.
```

which yesterday printed 'j', now it just prints an empty character.
I have used several websites and they all don't work.
Why?

Comment: Why do you expect it to print `j`? https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Maybe you got something to show you `^J` in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation but that's different from the letter `j`.

Comment: When I first used it, it began with the alphabet and not the ASCII table spaces...

Answer (score 0):

10 is the ASCII for a linefeed character, used to terminate lines in brainfuck. So this program should output a linefeed, and if you want to output a 'j' you should set the cell to 106. I'm curious what implementation and what settings got you a 'j' from that.